# How to get the path of the virtual folder in file save dialog?

Tags: c++, windows, registry, shell-extensions, shell-namespace-extension

----------------------------------**update**-----------------------------------
If I implement the `ParseDislayName` like following, dialog will report "The file already exist, do you want to replace it?":

```
HRESULT CFolderViewImplFolder::ParseDisplayName(HWND hwnd, IBindCtx *pbc, PWSTR pszName,
                                            ULONG *pchEaten, PIDLIST_RELATIVE *ppidl, ULONG *pdwAttributes)
{
HRESULT hr = E_INVALIDARG;

if (NULL != pszName)
{
    WCHAR szNameComponent[MAX_PATH] = {};

    // extract first component of the display name
    PWSTR pszNext = PathFindNextComponent(pszName);
    if (pszNext && *pszNext)
    {
        hr = StringCchCopyN(szNameComponent, ARRAYSIZE(szNameComponent), pszName, lstrlen(pszName) - lstrlen(pszNext));
    }
    else
    {
        hr = StringCchCopy(szNameComponent, ARRAYSIZE(szNameComponent), pszName);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PathRemoveBackslash(szNameComponent);

        UINT uIndex = 0;
        hr = GetIndexFromDisplayString(szNameComponent, &uIndex);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            BOOL fIsFolder = ISFOLDERFROMINDEX(uIndex);
            PIDLIST_RELATIVE pidlCurrent = NULL;
            hr = CreateChildID(szNameComponent, fIsFolder, &pidlCurrent);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                // If there are more components to parse, delegate to the child folder to handle the rest.
                if (pszNext && *pszNext)
                {
                    // Bind to current item
                    IShellFolder *psf;
                    hr = BindToObject(pidlCurrent, pbc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psf));
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        PIDLIST_RELATIVE pidlNext = NULL;
                        hr = psf->ParseDisplayName(hwnd, pbc, pszNext, pchEaten, &pidlNext, pdwAttributes);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            *ppidl = ILCombine(pidlCurrent, pidlNext);
                            ILFree(pidlNext);
                        }
                        psf->Release();
                    }

                    ILFree(pidlCurrent);
                }
                else
                {
                    // transfer ownership to caller
                    *ppidl = pidlCurrent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return hr;
}
```

---

I use shell namespace extension to create a virtual folder on windows 7.
Then I bring up a file "Save As" dialog in another application, and select a specific "folder" in the virtual folder in the dialog, the file dialog cannot get the path to the virtual folder.
After several experiments, I can get the path of the folder in the file "Open" dialog as described in this link:
[cannot get the path for the virtual folder on windows 7 C++(shell namespace extension related)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168882/cannot-get-the-path-for-the-virtual-folder-on-windows-7-cshell-namespace-exte)
But when I use a similar way to implement the file "Save As" dialog, it doesn't work.

```
class CDialogEventHandler : public IFileDialogEvents,
public IFileDialogControlEvents
{
public:
// IUnknown methods
IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
{
    static const QITAB qit[] = {
        QITABENT(CDialogEventHandler, IFileDialogEvents),
        QITABENT(CDialogEventHandler, IFileDialogControlEvents),
        { 0 },
    };
    return QISearch(this, qit, riid, ppv);
}

IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
{
    return InterlockedIncrement(&_cRef);
}

IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
{
    long cRef = InterlockedDecrement(&_cRef);
    if (!cRef)
        delete this;
    return cRef;
}

// IFileDialogEvents methods
IFACEMETHODIMP OnFileOk(IFileDialog *) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnFolderChange(IFileDialog *) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnFolderChanging(IFileDialog *, IShellItem *) { return S_OK; 
};
IFACEMETHODIMP OnHelp(IFileDialog *) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnSelectionChange(IFileDialog *) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnShareViolation(IFileDialog *, IShellItem *, FDE_SHAREVIOLATION_RESPONSE *) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnTypeChange(IFileDialog *pfd) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnOverwrite(IFileDialog *, IShellItem *, FDE_OVERWRITE_RESPONSE *) { return S_OK; };

// IFileDialogControlEvents methods
IFACEMETHODIMP OnItemSelected(IFileDialogCustomize *pfdc, DWORD dwIDCtl, DWORD dwIDItem) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnButtonClicked(IFileDialogCustomize *, DWORD) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnCheckButtonToggled(IFileDialogCustomize *, DWORD, BOOL) { return S_OK; };
IFACEMETHODIMP OnControlActivating(IFileDialogCustomize *, DWORD) { return S_OK; };

CDialogEventHandler() : _cRef(1) { };
private:
~CDialogEventHandler() { };
long _cRef;
};


HRESULT CDialogEventHandler_CreateInstance(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
*ppv = NULL;
CDialogEventHandler *pDialogEventHandler = new (std::nothrow) CDialogEventHandler();
HRESULT hr = pDialogEventHandler ? S_OK : E_OUTOFMEMORY;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pDialogEventHandler->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
    pDialogEventHandler->Release();
}
return hr;
}

HRESULT VirtualFolderFileSave()
{
// CoCreate the File Open Dialog object.
//IFileSaveDialog *pfsd; also doesn't work
IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileSaveDialog,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    
    IFileDialogEvents *pfde = NULL;
    hr = CDialogEventHandler_CreateInstance(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfde));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Hook up the event handler.
        DWORD dwCookie;
        hr = pfd->Advise(pfde, &dwCookie);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            
            DWORD dwFlags = 0;
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                
                hr = pfd->SetOptions(dwFlags | FOS_ALLNONSTORAGEITEMS | FOS_NOVALIDATE);

                hr = pfd->SetFileTypes(ARRAYSIZE(c_rgSaveTypes), c_rgSaveTypes);

                hr = pfd->SetDefaultExtension(L"apx");
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // Show the dialog
                    hr = pfd->Show(NULL);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        //never get here.......
                        IShellItem *psiResult;
                        hr = pfd->GetResult(&psiResult);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            
                            PWSTR pszFilePath = NULL;
                            hr = psiResult->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH,
                                &pszFilePath);
                            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                            {
                                
                            }
                            psiResult->Release();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            // Unhook the event handler.
            pfd->Unadvise(dwCookie);
        }
        pfde->Release();
    }
    pfd->Release();
}
return hr;
}
```

I add breakpoint in `IFACEMETHODIMP OnFileOk(IFileDialog *) { return S_OK; };` in the above code, but it is never triggered after I click "Save" button in the file dialog. And as you can see in the comments in the above code, after the dialog shows up, it never returns after `hr = pfd->Show(NULL);`. Every time when I click "Save" button, it always reports error or throw exceptions.

I tried to implement the following in the virtual folder dll,

```
//  Translates a display name into an item identifier list.
HRESULT CFolderViewImplFolder::ParseDisplayName(HWND /*hwnd*/, IBindCtx *  /*pbc*/, PWSTR /*pszName*/,
ULONG *  /*pchEaten*/, PIDLIST_RELATIVE *   /*ppidl*/, ULONG *  /*pdwAttributes*/)
{
   return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

But when it returns `E_NOTIMPL`, dialog reports "not implement"error, if it returns `S_OK`, dialog throws exceptions.
[image]

I am not trying to create something under virtual foder, I just want to get the path wthere the user is trying to save at.

Comment: If it is throwing an exception use the exception manager in VS (Debug->Windows->Exceptions) to break when that particular exception type is throw, if necessary add the exception to the right group ("Win32 Exceptions" for native code debugging). Then look at the stack and see exactly where things are going wrong.

Comment: The exceptions existing in a dll which is provided by C++. I know why the exception happens, but besides the exception, the error still exists. The dialog still validate the path and tell me error.

Comment: Implementing IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName *completely* is not really an option. Most things work w/o it, but you'll always come across apps and programs that need it, including the shell itself.

Comment: @SimonMourier  I implement all shell functions, but they only work for file Open dialog.

Comment: How do you implement ParseDisplayName? If this crashes Save file dialog, then you have a bug in your code.

Comment: @SimonMourier Not crash, I just simply let it return E_NOTIMPL; as you can see in the above, but dialog pops up "Not implemented".

Comment: Yes, that's what I say, you *must* implement it properly and fill the ppidl member, not return E_NOTIMPL, not return S_OK w/o doing anything.It's not an option: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093.aspx (although it seems to work in most cases if you return E_NOTIMPL).

Comment: Thanks. Do you see my update? I implement it like my updates, but it also has a problem.